# Shaded bootbox dialog

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, bootbox

I'm using [bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/) to create bootstrap modals. Here is how I'm creating a sample one:

```
bootbox.dialog({message: "hello"});
```

My problem is that the rendered dialog is kind of disabled (all screen is shaded), I can't click on it and even `ESC` cannot make the modal disappear!

When I inspect the dialog element in the browser this is what I see:

```
<div class="bootbox modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: block;" aria-hidden="false">
  <div class="modal-backdrop fade in" style="height: 321px;"></div>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="bootbox-close-button close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top: -10px;">×</button>
        <div class="bootbox-body">hello</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I checked with bootbox examples and it looks like it's the same CSS classes that have been used. So what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I've to to add the following CSS to fix the problem:

```
.modal-backdrop.fade.in {
  z-index: 0;
}
```